# jQuery UI date picker shows selected value incorrectly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following code which attaches the jQuery UI date picker widget to an input field:

```
    console.log($("#profileDialog .date-picker").val());
    $("#profileDialog .date-picker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        yearRange: "-115:-2",
        defaultDate: $("#profileDialog .date-picker").val()
    });
```

The console log outputs the value correctly (ex: `11/1/1955 12:00:00 AM`), but when I click inside the input field, the date picker shows me a selected date of `April 17 1897`.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: The jQuery UI datepipcker without modification only shows a date, not a time. Your console is showing the default date that you put into the input field. Upon changing the date, you'll lose the time. As for the `April 17 1897` format when you are setting it to `'yy-mm-dd'` I cannot replicate this. Can you create a jsFiddle that does this?

Comment: Just a guess but do you think it could be something to do with `yearRange`? `2012-115=1897`

Comment: I am almost absolutely sure it is the `dateFormat` or the `yearRange` that is causing the issue. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NZtVW/. The date is being sent from the server (ASP.NET MVC), so I'm not sure how I would go around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see `1897` as the year is because you're setting the `dateFormat` as `yy-mm-dd`, when the default date is in the format `dd-mm-yy`, which isn't a valid date (in the given format).

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NZtVW/3/)

Comment: Yes but that's not the format of the date that is being sent from the server.

Comment: @Kassem you're setting the format of the date when you pass the `dateFormat` to the datepicker object, so once you pick a date it will be in that format..

Comment: Ok now I understand what's going on. Thanks :)